# onNotification method not called

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Ionic Push for Push Notifications. I have successfully registered with the server and got the Token ID also (Called `reg_id` in Ionic).
I have followed all the steps as shown in Ionic Docs here http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-install.

But now when I try to send push notifications using the curl command, the notification is shown as sent but is never received by the app. If I check the status, I get the status as `success`. Please help

Comtroller Code: https://gist.github.com/samarthagarwal/833064a2de0660e826b6

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.